# Form fields injected into multiple beans with same property names

Tags: java, forms, spring, spring-mvc

So a problem should be really simple. I have a form, GET and POST controller methods and one form backing bean.

Relevant part of the form:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="newUser" method="post" action="${signUpUrl}">
    <table>

        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Username: </td>
            <td><c:out value="${userForEditBean.username}"/></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><form:password path="password" size="20"/>
            </td>
            <td><form:errors path="password" cssClass="error"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><input id="submitUser" name="Submit" value="Submit" type="submit" />  
        </tbody>
     </table>
</form:form>
```

GET method

```
...
model.addAttribute("newUser", new SignUpBean());
model.addAttribute("test", new InjectTest());
...
```

POST method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String registerUser(@ModelAttribute("test") InjectTest injTest, @ModelAttribute("newUser") SignUpBean signUpBean, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model)
...
```

So, when I click submit ALL of the beans which I retrieve from the model using `@ModelAttribute` in the POST method having a String property `password` (which are `signUpBean` and `injTest`) have the same contents in the password field, which is the password I entered into the form.

I don't want that, I want only the bean marked with the modelAttribute `newUser` to be populated.

I am using Spring 3.2.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a method annotated `InitBinder` to your controller which prevents the password being bound to the `InjectTest` bean.

```
@InitBinder("test")
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setDisallowedFields("password");
}
```